# Jest styled-components 4.1.1 test are broken

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, styled-components

Recently I've update to styled-components to 4.1.1 and most of the component test are broken. I simply create a dumb component to make a dummy test and see if it depends of how the others tests are made or is simply the current version of styled-components.

giving this Button component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  color: red;
`;
export default Button;
```

And here the relative test:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import 'jest-styled-components';
import Button from './Button';

test('it works', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<Button />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

the output is:

```
Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.
```

Can be caused to the latest version of styled-components and some other dependencies?

i didn't found anything in the official ducumentation.

Comment: Which version of `jest-styled-components` are you using?

Comment: `jest-styled-components@6.3.1`

Answer (score 1):

Are all of your React dependencies updated and version-synchronized? `react`, `react-dom`, `react-test-renderer`, and `react-is` should all be on the same version, ideally above 16.4.

Answer (score 0):

Ive had no end of issues using react-test-renderer and styled components. The way around this I found is to use another npm module called react-testing-library

then instead of

```
const tree = renderer.create(<Button />).toJSON();
```

use

```
const tree = render(<Button />).toJSON();
```

then

```
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

this should work!